# how to obtain code from repository using WinCvs

Tags: wincvs

I got a CVS connection string, here it is :

:ssh;username=dummy;password=dummy;hostname=repos.mooo.com:/home/projects/repos

How can I get project code using WinCvs, I've just installed it and I can't find howto online, maybe some help, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WinCVS 2.1, Click the Remote menu item, and select Checkout code.
On this screen click the ... next to CVSROOT, and you should bring up a dialog allowing you to enter the parameters you mention in your question (this is a bit easier to do than trying to enter the string manually).

You'll also need to enter a module name on the server, and a directory to check our the code into, but once you do this and click OK you should start checking out the code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use WinCVS with the PuTTY SSH tools to be able to connect securely. Check out the description [here](http://www.bcl.hamilton.ie/computers/wincvs_installation.html)

The site covers the following steps

- Download the required materials (WinCvs, PuTTY).
- Install the PuTTY SSH suite.
- Install WinCvs.
- Generate a SSH key pair.
- Upload your SSH key pair.
- Configure Pageant (a component of PuTTY).
- Test your automated authentication.
- Configure WinCvs.
- Start using WinCvs

Comment: Sorry m8 your answer might be correct but it had just too many steps to follow, Johns answer was more simple. Sometimes less is more. Thank you

Comment: As I remember your WinCVS doesn't support SSH on it's own. You'll be sending code, username and password in the clear.